# Change background color for referenced selector as image source for ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an image that I want to change from a black background to a gray background when pressed, and using a selector seemed like the best way to do that, but the color isn't changing. I can get the image to change on click, but I want to just change the background color. I'd rather not use an onClickListener just b/c this seems cleaner. Here's my code:

Image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/image_block"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/image_btn"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:src="@drawable/image_selector"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/image_gray"
    android:background="@color/gray"/>
  <item
    android:drawable="@drawable/image_gray"
    android:background="@color/black"/>
</selector>
```

LogCat for when StackOverflow was happening (a clean fixed it):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ex.package/com.ex.package.ImageActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
at dcom.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:375)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1997)
        at com.ex.package.ImageActivity.onCreate(ImageActivity.java:33)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2552)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839)
        a

t android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
              at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:375)
              at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1997)
              at com.ex.package.ImageActivity.onCreate(ImageActivity.java:33)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2552)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
            at android.util.LongSparseArray.get(LongSparseArray.java:111)
            at android.util.LongSparseArray.get(LongSparseArray.java:102)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getCachedDrawable(Resources.java:2226)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2086)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:711)
            at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:176)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:937)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2130)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:711)
            at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:176)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:937)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2130)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:711)
            at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:176)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:937)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
            at android.content.res.Resources.l
```

Any help would be awesome.

Thanks,
Devin

Comment: The name of the image in one of the drawable folders.

Comment: I suggest that it is huge. Am I right?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. The image is so big it's causing a stack overflow? It worked perfectly when I accessed it directly in the image file. It's 95x95. 1.67 Kb.

Comment: What's size of image(kb) and resolution?

Comment: From the stack trace, it would seem that a `<selector>` references itself, either directly or indirectly. If that's not the case, try cleaning the project.

Comment: Of course that fixed it. Now, how do I get the background colors to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<item>` has no attribute `android:background`. All the fields in it [are listed here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).

If you *only* want the background to change when the item is tapped, change the ImageView's `android:src` to `@drawable/image_gray` and change its `android:background` a selector that only toggles between `@color/gray` and `@color/black` for its main drawable.

It'd look something like this:

```
  <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/image_btn"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
  android:src="@drawable/image_gray"/>
```

where background_selector.xml is something like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/gray"/>
  <item
    android:drawable="@color/black"/>
</selector>
```

Also as a side note, if your `ImageView` is tappable consider changing it to an `ImageButton`.

Comment: Beautiful! I didn't even think about putting it in the background. What's the best way to set the `ImageButton` as selected so it will also stay gray until another button in the same row is selected? Do I need to manually set a button's state to selected?

Comment: @DevinCrane When a button in the set you care about is selected, reset all other buttons to use the selector, then manually set its background. You can probably use one single `OnClickListener` for all of them to do this. Don't piggy-back off the android states to do what you can do manually.

Comment: doesn't that defeat the purpose of the selector?

Comment: @DevinCrane the selectors are made for *very* specific scenarios. The one you're using right now is for tapping on an item. The `selected` state is only supposed to be used in `ListView`s, as far as I know.

Comment: What's the best way to solve this same problem if all the buttons are now being stored statically? I'm willing to completely rearrange my code if necessary.

Comment: @DevinCrane what do you mean statically? Perhaps update your question with more info?

Comment: When my app starts up, I create the buttons and an `onClickListener` for each and store them in a static `ImageButton` variable. I still need them to highlight when selected and unhighlight when another one is selected. Currently, they are displayed in a `LinearLayout`. When a button is selected, a new `Activity` is started. I'm still manually setting them to selected, but it somehow isn't sticking; it reverts back to the default button. I'm thinking about using a `TabHost`.

Answer (score 0):

For those curious, I changed my `ImageView` to an `ImageButton`. When I set an `ImageButton`'s state_selected to true through code, it does set the background color to whatever is set in the selector item:

```
<item
  android:state_selected="true"
  android:drawable="@color/gray"/>
```

But then, of course, to unselect it, you have to set state_selected to false. 
This would be done with the following: `imageButton.setSelected(<true or false>);`
This state is specifically made for `ImageButton`s, as shown [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html).